# Как правильно: "в Кавминводах" или "на Кавминводах"?

Tags: предлоги

Какой предлог надо употреблять в словосочетаниях:

- *отдыхать на Кавминводах* или *отдыхать в Кавминводах*
- *поехать в Кавминводы* или *поехать на Кавминводы*
- *основать общество на Кавминводах* или *основать общество в Кавминводах*

Answer (score 2):

Кавминводы (КМВ) - формализованное наименование административного региона. Поэтому можно не озадачиваться концепцией поездки "на (кавказские минеральные) воды" и употребить предлог "в", совместимый с видовым наименованием "района" или "региона" (куда - "в него"). Можно отдыхать "на водах", находясь "в Кавминводах".